# iOS App started crashing without updates

Tags: ios, crashlytics

My app was updated 3 months ago.
And was working 100% fine (Crashlytics had more than 96% crash free users)
Yesterday - 2/1/2018 all of a sudden i received a late night email from crashlytics that there is an issue with my app.
And all of the users that were trying to enter on a viewcontroller from a tab bar was crashing.

http://crashes.to/s/1132ba4b6ff

I understand that the pod `JTAppleCalendar` is not on the latest version ok.
But for 3 months everything was ok and in one night there is an issue.

As far as my mind goes, Apple is secretly updating their libraries and not only on iOS updates.
Has anyone experienced anything like this before?

The swift file is the following (with the version i use)

https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/blob/6.1.6/Sources/JTAppleCalendarView.swift

and its in the line 283.

The updated pod version works fine. Although now i'm uploading a new version this is really weird.

FYI. All I'm trying to do is to raise awareness because i'm not sure if Apple has informed developers that they do
 background updates on their libraries.

Comment: You'll get better help if you update your question to include the relevant code and crash information in your question as text, not as links.

Comment: Presumably `cachedConfiguration.numberOfRows` is 0.  This could be a result of some date-related bug that is being triggered now. It seems unlikely to be the result of an Apple update.

Comment: @Paulw11 and is being triggered after many months ? i don’t know ...

Comment: It is a new year.  That is a prime time for date related bugs.  With such a high occurrence rate it shouldn't be very hard for you to replicate and debug.  Where in your code do you calculate the number of rows and put it in the configuration?

Comment: How soon can you implement the latest version? I can help.

Comment: @iOSCalendarViewOnMyProfile its is released today.

Comment: @Paulw11 there was nothing to do with configuration.

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios let me know if this is still happening on the latest released version.